# Test Driven Laravel, testing views: integers

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-blade

**How would you correctly test an integer value of a view?**

Laravel version 5.6.

Consider the code below.

```
// ViewMatchTest
$response->assertSee($match->goals_away); // checks if "0" is in the view
$reponse->assertSee($match->start_time); // checks if "13:00" is in the view

// match\show.blade.php
<li> {{ $match->goals_away }} </li>
<li> {{ $match->start_time }} </li>
```

If you would run this test, then it outputs: "OK".
But even if you remove the line:

```
<li> {{ $match->goals_away }} </li>
```

The test would still pass because of the "0" in the start_time (13:00) of that match.

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.6 is the current version

Comment: How about `assertSourceHas("<li>{$match->goals_away}</li>")` ?

Comment: Unfortunately that would not work. What if the frontend developer takes the decision to replace the li tags with a p-tag?

Comment: That will break your test and you will need to update it. However it's better to get test fails on UI change than a test passing when test should be failing. Looking for a string of 0 is much to generic to work.

Comment: You can also consider adding ids to your elements like e.g. `<li id='goals-away'>...</li>` and doing `assertSeeIn("#goals-away", $match->goals_away)` and instruct your UI designers to keep the ids. However that will also break if `goals_away` is 10 and you need to see 0

Comment: I agree with you that it is better for a test to be successful when you expect it. For now I use the assertHasSource method.